# How do I use the information (gibberish) obtained from the Unofficial XBOX API?

Tags: git, api, xbox

Exactly what the title says: When I use this API in order to get my profile data using the GIT program, I do get some valid information in the beginning, but its extremely hard to read and is followed by a bunch of gibberish like:

":"78f1565d-1811-46c9-99cb-4bc95030ac65","Url":"https://dlassets-ssl.xboxlive.com/public/content/78f1565d-1811-46c9-99cb-4bc95030ac65/1fe2359e-e36c-4cb2-9943-4582f053b314/319fa247-1c7a-42d0-9213-7d0e7d8bd0f0.png","ResizeUrl":"http://images-eds.xboxlive.com\"

I would like to know how to or where at least to start in order to take this information and make it readable, formatted, and usable.

Comment: What are you trying to read/format/use it for? This is clearly only part of the JSON you are getting back, and it is not particularly possible to help without further explanation/code. `78f1565d-1811-46c9-99cb-4bc95030ac65` seems to be a user ID of some sort, and the Url field contains `https://dlassets-ssl.xboxlive.com/public/content/78f1565d-1811-46c9-99cb-4bc95030ac65/1fe2359e-e36c-4cb2-9943-4582f053b314/319fa247-1c7a-42d0-9213-7d0e7d8bd0f0.png`, which uses this ID when storing an image file. It might be easier to identify what ResizeUrl is for if you could provide more insight.

Comment: I think you can disregard that random snippet of code. I just get hundreds of lines of code like that and I'm unsure of how to go about doing anything about them. I will post a link to a call I made to the Xbox Live Store Page however for a better idea of what I'm asking about http://prntscr.com/dwjybe

Comment: oh and I'm just trying to figure out how to use this API is all. I can make calls to it, but I'm not sure what (and how) to do with the information after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the owner, and developer of XboxAPI. All data returned from XboxAPI is in JSON format. This means that depending on the programming language (most, if not all) you can parse JSON out to an object/array.

If you are using a linux or unix (mac os) system, then you can use cURL and pipe that into `json_pp` or `jsonpp`. This will format the JSON in a readable mannor. An example of this, with getting screenshots is as follows;

`curl -H "X-AUTH: YOUR_AUTH_KEY_HERE" https://xboxapi.com/v2/2533274813081462/screenshots | json_pp`

This will format the response into a readable format. Now if you are on windows, then I can't help you with that, however if you are willing to learn just a little PHP (very easy to learn the basics), then you can get all this information very very easily - `cl.ly/3R0E090B0v1Q` (can't link as Stackoverflow thinks its a shortened link)

If you are just wanting to view the data in the browser, then I would recommend using Chrome, and the following plugin to make the data readable - https://github.com/callumlocke/json-formatter

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you redirect the output to file. If you are making the API call via a terminal command, this is very simple: `>` directs the output of a command into a file. e.g. `command > out.txt`.

You will then need to remove escape characters (e.g. you will see `\/` a lot where `/` is what you are expecting), in order to be able to format it nicely. There are [some nice services](http://www.freeformatter.com/javascript-escape.html) which you might be able to use for this.

[JSON Pretty Print](http://jsonprettyprint.com) is a nice service for providing quick formatting to JSON. However, it looks as though your JSON response may be too big for this to handle, and you may need to find another way.

Once you have this, it should be much clearer what the body of the JSON is for, and how you can go about accessing what you are interested in.

Comment: Thank you for the help. This should at least guide me in the right direction!